# UEFI c++: when using Print, wchar_t convertion error happens

Tags: c++, g++, uefi, gnu-efi

I want to try to make a little (U)EFI bootloader in c++, but, when I try to compile my code (with g++) gives this error:

```
boot.cpp: In function ‘EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE*)’:
boot.cpp:9:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const CHAR16*’ {aka ‘const short unsigned int*’} [-fpermissive]
    9 |   Print(L"Hello, world!\n");
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         const wchar_t*
In file included from boot.cpp:2:
/usr/include/efi/efilib.h:504:24: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘UINTN Print(const CHAR16*, ...)’
  504 |     IN CONST CHAR16   *fmt,
```

I used this comand (i working from Ubuntu WSL2):

```
g++ boot.cpp -mno-red-zone -ffreestanding -fshort-wchar -nostdlib -e efi_main -Wl,-dll -shared -Wl,--subsystem,10 -c -I/usr/include/efi/ -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64/
```

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable)
{
  InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
  Print(L"Hello, world!\n");
  return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT:**
If i remove L from "Hello, world\n", gives me this error:

```
boot.cpp: In function ‘EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE*)’:
boot.cpp:9:9: error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘const CHAR16*’ {aka ‘const short unsigned int*’}
    9 |   Print("Hello, world!\n");
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         const char*
In file included from boot.cpp:2:
/usr/include/efi/efilib.h:504:24: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘UINTN Print(const CHAR16*, ...)’
  504 |     IN CONST CHAR16   *fmt,
```

**EDIT 2:**
If i use u in front of hello world (u"Hello,world\n") gives this error:

```
boot.cpp: In function ‘EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE*)’:
boot.cpp:9:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char16_t*’ to ‘const CHAR16*’ {aka ‘const short unsigned int*’} [-fpermissive]
    9 |   Print(u"Hello, world!\n");
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         const char16_t*
In file included from boot.cpp:2:
/usr/include/efi/efilib.h:504:24: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘UINTN Print(const CHAR16*, ...)’
  504 |     IN CONST CHAR16   *fmt,
```

Comment: The error is telling you it doesn't know how to convert from `wchar_t` to the type that the `Print` function expects, why not remove the `L` preprended to the string?

Comment: `wchar_t` is 32-bit on Linux. `Print` expects 16-bit characters. Try `u"Hello, world!\n"`.

Comment: I used -fshort-wchar for 16bit

Comment: Have you tried constructing the string literal outside of the function call? `const CHAR16* mystr = "Hello world\n"`.

Comment: "I used -fshort-wchar" They are still different types.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `Print` coming from? It seems that it is not appropriate for your compiler.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve, use gcc instead of g++ and cast to CHAR16*